# Django-graphene multiple types for the same model

Tags: python, django, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a quite big `graphene-django` API which feeds two applications.

My first approach to restrict access to some fields was to have multiple `DjangoObjectTypes` for the same model, and use `fields` to limit which fields can be accessed on each type.

Example for `Organization`:

```py
class OrganizationType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "members"
            "date_created",
            "last_modified",
        )
```

```py
class LiteOrganizationType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
        )
```

Is this the best approach or should I have only one type and resolve fields based on the current user/app/etc..?

The main issue I have experienced is that I need to explicitly define which type to use then in other related types.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is providing more fields than necessary okay? The beauty of GraphQL is that the client can request only the fields they want

Comment: This is the way forward, one you use for Public APIs and one for Private APIs, yep, the other way is to resolve each field individually and check if user has permission for it, but you don't want to go through that route. This will more than suffice.

Comment: @frozenOne Yes, but the question is how to explicitly specify which field to use.  It's very concerning that graphene_django just automatically selects one.  I can't accept the risk associated with not having these explicitly defined.

Am digging through the graphene_django code now to see what I can learn.

Comment: I created a more specific question similar to this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70826464/graphene-django-determine-object-type-when-multiple-graphql-object-types-use, but press having multiple object types for the same model being a _fixed decision_. I believe this is in the confines of what graphql is designed to do. graphene-django, despite being sent a typed relay ID, returns other object types if they match the django model.

Answer (score 0):

for me works order the classes based on its quantity of fields, from the class with less fields to class with more fields.
In your case

```
# First the class with less fields
class LiteOrganizationType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
        )

# Last the class with more fields.
class OrganizationType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "members"
            "date_created",
            "last_modified",
        )
```

And that's all.