# graphene-django: Determine Object type when multiple GraphQL object types use the same django model in node query

Tags: django, graphene-django

This is specifically for [graphene-django](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django) (*not* just [graphene](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene)) when performing a [`node(id: ...) {}`](https://graphql.org/learn/global-object-identification/) query.

Assume a fixed schema with 2 (or more) different GraphQL object types using `graphene_django.DjangoObjectType` linked to the *same* django model:

```python
import graphene_django
from .models import Org as OrgModel

class Org(graphene_django.DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = OrgModel
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "billing"
        )

class AnonymousOrg(graphene_django.DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = OrgModel
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
        )
```

Let's assume a query to `Org` of ID `7eca71ed-ff04-4473-9fd1-0a587705f885`.

```js
btoa('Org:7eca71ed-ff04-4473-9fd1-0a587705f885')
'T3JnOjdlY2E3MWVkLWZmMDQtNDQ3My05ZmQxLTBhNTg3NzA1Zjg4NQ=='
```

```graphql
{
  node(id: "T3JnOjdlY2E3MWVkLWZmMDQtNDQ3My05ZmQxLTBhNTg3NzA1Zjg4NQ==") {
    id
    __typename
    ... on Org {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Return:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "node": {
      "id": "QW5vbnltb3VzT3JnOjdlY2E3MWVkLWZmMDQtNDQ3My05ZmQxLTBhNTg3NzA1Zjg4NQ==",
      "__typename": "AnonymousOrg"
    }
  }
}
```

It returns the other object type `'AnonymousOrg:7eca71ed-ff04-4473-9fd1-0a587705f885'`, despite the relay ID specifying it was an `Org` object.

Is there a way in graphene-django to "hint" or provide detail to assure the return type if what's specified in the ID and its fragment?

**Clarification on question**

Other questions were discussing [graphene](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene), not specifically [graphene-django](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django), which is doing the type determinations in this case.

This is different from [Django-graphene multiple types for the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641512/django-graphene-multiple-types-for-the-same-model), as that one asked about how to handle field permissions and opened possibility to reconsidering schema structure (e.g. splitting between Public and Private API schemas) - that isn't a choice in this question.

Credit: This is graphene django models are based on the ones from the question at [Django-graphene multiple types for the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641512/django-graphene-multiple-types-for-the-same-model).

P.S. I created a bug issue on the tracker here: [graphene-django#1291](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/1291) named "`DjangoObjectType` using the same django model do not resolve to correct relay object". Supposedly this issue was resolved years ago, but communication lines got crossed.

Answer (score 0):

The credit to this goes to [@Boolangery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5136476/boolangery) ([GitHub](https://github.com/boolangery))'s [workaround](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/971#issuecomment-633507631) on May 25th, 2020.

```py
class FixRelayNodeResolutionMixin:
    @classmethod
    def get_node(cls, info, pk):
        instance = super(FixRelayNodeResolutionMixin, cls).get_node( info, pk)
        setattr(instance, "graphql_type", cls.__name__)
        return instance

    @classmethod
    def is_type_of(cls, root, info):
        if hasattr(root, "graphql_type"):
            return getattr(root, "graphql_type") == cls.__name__
        return super(FixRelayNodeResolutionMixin, cls).is_type_of(root, info)
```

Usage, here is an example with a django `User` model with two Django Graphene objects pointing to it: `PublicUserType` and `UserType`:

```py
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType


class PublicUserType(FixRelayNodeResolutionMixin, DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']

class UserType(FixRelayNodeResolutionMixin, DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile']
```

Comment: The credit for above goes to [this post](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/971#issuecomment-633507631) on GitHub on May 25th, 2020. For now I've made this into a wiki.

Answer (score 0):

today I was the same issue and I solved it as [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641512/django-graphene-multiple-types-for-the-same-model/73706769#73706769)

For me works reorder the classes types from class type with less fields to class type with more fields.

So,

```
class AnonymousOrg(graphene_django.DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = OrgModel
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
        )

class LiteOrg(graphene_django.DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = OrgModel
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "billing"
        )

class OrgAll(graphene_django.DjangoObjectType):
        class Meta:
            model = OrgModel
            fields = '__all__'
```